# OpenGL multiple render targets and multisampling

Tags: c++, opengl, multisampling, deferred-rendering, msaa

I am having problems using explicit multisampling when using multiple rendering targets in OpenGL.

I have 4 render targets (Position, Diffuse + opacity, Normal, Specular + exponent) that are rendered to during the initial geometry pass.

These are all non multisampled textures attached to a framebuffer object, and then set as the render targets using glDrawBuffers(). This works fine, and I can then sample these textures later to get the information needed for lighting calculations. Lovely.

[image: Without multisampled textures. MRT works fine.]

I now want to try to remove some of the aliasing I am getting, so I started to implement explicit MSAA using multisampled textures. However, when I use multisampled textures as the render targets instead, only the first render target seems to be drawn to and the rest remain blank.

[image: With multisampled textures. Only rendered to the first drawbuffer.]

Other than changing how the textures are setup, bound and read in the shaders I haven't changed any other code.

Multisampled textures are attached to the framebuffer object using this code:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < textureCount; ++i)
{
    // Generate texture
    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);    

    // Bind multisample texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, texture);
    glTexImage2DMultisample(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, msaaSamples, GL_RGBA, width, height, false);

    // Set params
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    // Attach to frame buffer
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i, GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, texture, 0);

    // Unbind
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 0);
}
```

Multisampled depth/stencil texture is attached as well.

```
glGenTextures(1, &depth);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, depth);
glTexImage2DMultisample(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, msaaSamples, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, width, height, false);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, depth, 0);
```

The framebuffer is then bound and draw buffers set

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
GLuint attachments[4] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3 };
glDrawBuffers(4,  attachments);
```

I then draw the geometry as usual. However, when inspecting with apitrace it is clear that only the first color attachment is being drawn into. This is not the case when I use regular (non-multisampled textures).

All 4 draw buffers are definetly still being set however.

[image: 4 draw buffers set.]

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the code. It is impossible to help without that.

Comment: Added what code could be relevant, and also 2 pictures to highlight the issue.

Comment: Do you have a multisamples depth/stencil attachment, too?

Comment: What's also suspicious is the line `GLuint attachments[2] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT4 }`. It should be array size 4, not 2, The attachment count should also begin with 0.

Comment: If changing "attachments[2]" to "attachments[4]" doesn't fix it, then calling glCheckFramebufferStatus after binding the framebuffer might help with diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Sorry attachments[2] was a typo, in the code the array size is 4. The frame buffer does have multisampled depth/stencil attachment as well, I can post the code used to attach that if needed. glCheckFramebufferStatus returns GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE, so it isn't an issue with the framebuffer. The issue is more I cannot seem to draw to multiple render targets when the framebuffer has multisample textures instead of non-multisampled textures.

Comment: Well, those screenshots hint that in your multisampled case, there is only one color attachment. I don't know why this is. Are you sure you end up with the correct FBO at all?

Comment: Looking using apitrace, when I bind the framebuffer it shows up that it has 4 colour attachments, 1 depth and 1 stencil. This seems correct as it should have 4 textures for attributes, and then a depth / stencil attachment. I agree however it looks as if only one colour attachment is being used. I am definetly calling glDrawBuffers() with the correct attachments as they show up in the apitrace parameter list shown in the screenshot above.

Answer (score 0):

glTexParameterf cannot be used with GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE.

Apart from this I would set the 'fixedsamplelocations'-param of glTexImage2DMultisample to true just to be on the safe side regarding hardware compatibility.

And I recommend to use a sized format like GL_RGBA8 instead of GL_RGBA (don't know how you managed to get GL_RGBA32F as listed in the first image with the unsized GL_RGBA enum...).